# Connect to Azure AD from Apache web server on windows

Tags: apache, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

I am trying to use Azure AD to authenticate a website in Apache web server deployed on a windows server. A possible solution we were looking for is mod_auth_openidc, however, it is not available for windows.

Are there any other options that can be used to authenticate a website in apache on a windows server?

Comment: mod_auth_openidc for Windows is available under a commercial agreement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design pattern should work in any technology since HTTP interfaces are used:

- Reverse proxy is the public URL
- Website uses an Internal URL
- Reverse proxy deals with OAuth and talks to Azure AD

Note that it is generally recommended in terms of secure hosting to put a reverse proxy in front of any of these components, so that an attacker has to breach 2 layers to get to data:

- APIs
- Web back ends that access data sources
- Authorization Servers

Here is an option that might work for you - and once you have a good reverse proxy setup it gives you some interesting architectural options:

- Use an [Azure NGINX managed service](https://www.nginx.com/partners/microsoft-azure/) which will use Linux based servers, but you don't need to know anything much about Linux to use them
- Use the [NGINX openidc module](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc) - also provided by Zmartzone - and host that alongside Azure AD

If it helps, at Curity we have some related resources - [here is one](https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-dynamic-user-routing/) that shows how to run NGINX on a Windows PC using Docker and how to take control over behaviour via plugins.